# Sorting a JTable column containing strings in a specific order

Tags: java, swing, sorting

I have a `JTable` containing 6 columns of different values. 
One of the columns is called "`Priority`" and contains the different Strings:

```
 ("Critical", "High", "Medium", "Low", "Not a priority").
```

The default sorting is alphabetical and is not working for this situation where I want to list the priority from low to high or the opposite.

I have been looking at Comparators and enums, but have not figured out how to make it work yet.

Also using this model:

```
public class TableModel extends DefaultTableModel{ 
     final Class<?>[] columnClasses = new Class<?>[] {Integer.class, String.class, Date.class, String.class, String.class, String.class}; 
     @Override 
     public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) { 
           return columnClasses[columnIndex]; 
     }
}
```

This have allowed me to automatically sort Dates and Integers in ascending and descending order.

Comment: Start by having a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer), this way you can have one value in the model and renderer it differently for the view

Comment: I'd also take a look at [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) more closely, you could, for example, use a `enum` which holds a value which you can sort by and use a custom sorter to sort the columns this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little example for comparators and enums

```
public enum Priority implements Comparable<Priority> {
    CRITICAL("Critical", 10), HIGH("High", 8), MEDIUM("Medium", 5), LOW("Low", 3), NONE("Not a priority", 0);
    String title;
    int value;

    public Priority(String aTitle, int aValue) {
        title = aTitle;
        value = aValue;
    }
    public int compareTo(Priority another) {
        return Integer.valueOf(value).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(another.value));
    }
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

You can replace the string values in your model by the enum constants. Method `toString` allows to display the correct string in table. Integer value is used for comparision (it's not implicitly required when the constants are in the correct order).